# Error de sintaxis SQL en MySQL server (Dreamweaver)

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

eh estado actualizando recientemente este código de un sistema y mas temprano que tarde me percate que es un código muy viejo y que utiliza las guías de Dreamweaver (o algo así tengo entendido), así que eh ido actualizando poco a poco el sistema pero eh chocado completamente con esto y ya no se que hacer, quería ver si podían echarme una mano o darme algunos consejos, para empezar este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y este es el código:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["huserok"]))
    {
        header("Location:" . "inicial.php");
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        exit;
    } 
      require ('MySite.php');
      //mysql_select_db($database_MySite, $MySite);   
      $usuario=$_SESSION['huserok'];
      $query_user = "SELECT usu_nivel FROM usuarios WHERE usu_usuario='$usuario'";
      $user= mysqli_query($MySite, $query_user) or die("Hola");
      $row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user);    
      $nivel = $row_user['usu_nivel'];    
    if ($nivel > 4)
    {header("Location:" . "inicial.php");}
    

$vid=$_GET['id'];

function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL"; ////ANTES (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue; ////SE DEBE A QUE ESTA OBSOLETO get_magic_quotes_gpc()

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form2")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE usuarios SET usu_clave=%s WHERE usu_IDUsuario=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['usu_clave'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['usu_IDUsuario'], "int"));

$Result1 = mysqli_query($MySite, $updateSQL) or die (mysqli_error($MySite));//ANTES mysqli_error() estaba vacio el parentesis y se necesitaba conectar a la base de datos, por eso puse el la variable como parametro $MySite 
 
  $ira = "inicial.php";
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $ira));
}

$query_update = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where usu_IDUsuario=$vid ";
$update = mysqli_query($MySite, $query_update) or die(mysqli_error($MySite));//ANTES mysqli_error() estaba vacio el parentesis y se necesitaba conectar a la base de datos, por eso puse el la variable como parametro $MySite 
$row_update = mysqli_fetch_assoc($update);

?>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function validar()
{if (document.form2.usu_clave.value== ""){alert("Ingrese una Contrae�a");return(false);} 
else if (document.form2.usu_clave_2.value==""){alert("Ingrese de nuevo la Contrase�a");return(false);}

    clave1 = document.form2.usu_clave.value
    clave2 = document.form2.usu_clave_2.value
    
    if (clave1 == clave2)
        {alert("Su Contrase�a ha sido cambiada Satisfactoriamente");return(true);}
    else
        {alert("Las Contrase�as no coinciden");return(false);}
        }
</SCRIPT>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"></link>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Cambiar Contrase&ntilde;a</title>
</head>

<body link="#ffffff" vlink="#ffffff" alink="000000">
<h1>Cambiar Contrase&ntilde;a</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<form method="post" name="form2" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" onSubmit="return validar(this)">
<table >
    <tr>
      <td width="230" ><b><?php echo ucwords($row_update['usu_nombre']);?></b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><b><?php echo strtoupper($row_update['usu_usuario']);?></b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>  <p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Ingrese Nueva Contrase&ntilde;a: </td>
      <td width="175">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="usu_clave" value="" size="20" maxlength="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td >Vuelva a Escribir la Contrase&ntilde;a: </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="usu_clave_2" value="" size="20" maxlength="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td aling="right">&nbsp;</td> <!--aling reintegrado (antes simplemente estaba en rojo)-->
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Aceptar"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form2">
    <input type="hidden" name="usu_IDUsuario" value="<?php echo $row_update['usu_IDUsuario']; ?>">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!--<a href="inicial.php" target="inicial"><img src="images\volver.bmp"></a>-->
</p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php mysqli_free_result($update);?>
```

Eh intentado muchas cosas pero me da que el error principal puede estar en la forma de la función de GetSQLValueString, seguiré indagando pero apreciaria mucho una ayudita.

Comment: mysql no estan estricto con los valores, si envias un int como '1', lo ingresa como int

Comment: Hola! disculpa, no estoy entendiendo muy bien tu comentario, podrías ser mas especifico?

Comment: Como el error es de syntaxis puede ser varias cosas, como una declaracion incorrecta, ejemplo, hacer un insert o un select a una columna que no existe, para hacer debug en esos casos, lo que hago es hacer un echo de la cadena de la consulta SQL y la reviso en un cliente de MySQL para asi detectar donde estaria el error

Comment: En esta linea pareciera que estuviera el error: UPDATE usuarios SET usu_clave=%s WHERE usu_IDUsuario=%s

Comment: puede que el id que estas insertando este ligado a una llave foránea y como no existe estas generando un error. has que se imprima la consulta y tira la consulta en la base de datos para ver mas específicamente que esta fallando

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, revisare justo lo que comentan